# Rails - Need help understanding Many-Many Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a project that requires a many-many relationship between books and users.

A book can be borrowed by many users (it has a # of copies property to define max # of users it can be borrowed by) and a user can borrow many books.

I created the models and the schema but I'm having trouble understanding how the data is saved in the databases as well as how to access them.

```
***Models***
class Book < ApplicationRecord

    has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end


class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  
  has_and_belongs_to_many :books
end

***Schema***
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2021_10_06_190918) do

  create_table "books", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.integer "total_copies"
    t.integer "copies_available"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.integer "book_id"
    t.index ["book_id"], name: "index_books_on_book_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.string "name"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

end
```

After reading some documentation about this `has_and_belongs_to_many` association I attempted to create the joins table migration with this line: `rails g migration book_users user_id:integer book_id:integer` However after pushing the migration, it doesn't look like the joins table was created?

What I am looking to do:

1. As a user, I can click a book to borrow it (adding my userID to the book's "borrowee" list)
2. I can click a book and display which users are currently borrowing this book
3. As a user, display which books I am currently borrowing

Answer (score 1):

- For many-to-many you **do** need a third table. Note that if using `has_and_belongs_to_many` your migration should create `books_users` (note 's' in both cases) table for Rails to recognize it as an intermediate table.
- My personal preference was always with `has_many through` because it allows you to have `id` on the intermediate table and an actual Model file for the relation in case you later want to add more logic to it (validations, sending email on new borrow etc)

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many